# Why is that a union of views works but when I create a view out of union of view, it fails

Tags: sql, oracle

In ORACLE, I am trying to create a view which is a union of view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW "TEST_ALL"
AS 

( SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) as DT,  M_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_ID) as RESULT
FROM VIEW1
UNION ALL

SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) as DT,  M_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_ID) as RESULT
FROM VIEW
UNION ALL

SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) as DT,  M_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_ID) as RESULT
FROM VIEW3
UNION ALL

SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) as DT,  M_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_ID) as RESULT
FROM VIEW4
UNION ALL

SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) as DT,  M_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_ID) as RESULT
FROM VIEW5
UNION ALL

SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) as DT,  M_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_ID) as RESULT
FROM VIEW6
)
```

This does not work? However when I remove `M_ID`, it creates the view.

Also when I just union all the inner views it works. Can someone please help?

Comment: You have a typo in `SELECT ... FROM VIEW` it should be `SELECT ... FROM VIEW2`. Fix that and your code works [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ofRw6z9P)

Answer (score 1):

In the query:

```sql
SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) as DT,
       M_ID,
       COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_ID) as RESULT
FROM   VIEW1
```

Then:

- `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP)` is effectively constant for all the rows;
- `COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_ID)` is an aggregation; and
- `M_ID` is an un-aggregated column.

You are mixing aggregated and un-aggregated columns and do not have a `GROUP BY` clause.

Either change each sub-query to:

1. ```sql
   SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) as DT,
          M_ID,
          COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_ID) as RESULT
   FROM   VIEW1
   GROUP BY M_ID
   ```
2. Or use an analytic function to generate the count:

   ```sql
   SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) as DT,
          M_ID,
          COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_ID) OVER () as RESULT
   FROM   VIEW1
   ```

And repeat for each of the views you ar `UNION`ing together.

Comment: Thank you for helping. For me, even the M_ID is a constant and is CHAR

Comment: It is not working as intended. Instead of giving just 6 records, it is giving me 7000 records

Comment: Use `group by` solution (1) from this answer. If M_ID is really constant for all records in view1, as you wrote, then this sub-query will return only one record. Check it first,

Comment: @Notacoder22 `M_ID` cannot be a constant as it is an identifier for a column of the view; it may be a column that only has a single value across all the rows but the SQL engine cannot know that.

Comment: i understand , but how come the union of all views work without group by? The problem arises when I create a outer view around it

Comment: @MT0 - Can you please elaborate a bit more. Why it cannot be a constant? 

 in the individual view, it was defined as constant. e.g. In View1 it was defined as :'M001' as M_ID

Comment: @Notacoder22 This is why you need to provide a [MRE] in the question and give the `CREATE VIEW` statements that define the views that your view depends upon; without the crucial context of how you define the parent views then the question appears to be about one thing when it is actually a simple typo.

Comment: Sorry. I thought it will be too much of query in question. Here is how the view looks like


Create View 'View1'
( WE_DATE , WE_M_ID, WE_RESULT) 
AS SELECT * FROM

( SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP), 'M001' as M_ID, OBJECT_ID
 FROM XYZ
INNER JOIN ( Some query)
ON condiiton
)

Comment: @MT0 :  Can you please help me understand?

Comment: @Notacoder22 See [my comment on your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76435021/76435064#comment134778121_76435021). Your code works if you don't have a typo and write `VIEW` instead of `VIEW2`; fix that and everything works (provided you are using constants for `M_ID` in all the views).

Comment: Thank you, It works. Can you please elaborate more on your comment :  M_ID cannot be a constant as it is an identifier for a column of the view; it may be a column that only has a single value across all the rows but the SQL engine cannot know that

Comment: @Notacoder22 Initially, you had not provided a [MRE] and were selecting `M_ID` that looked like a column value from a table and, using that assumption, then my comment is correct that the SQL engine would not know that the value was constant even if it was identical in all rows of the table. When you later provided the code for the view and we found out that `M_ID` was not a column from a table and was defined as a literal value then, in that specific case that was not obvious when you asked the question, then it is a constant and your code works (if you fix the typo).